# Where is the code for web3 version 0.20.x?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I'm using the following:

```
truffle(development)> version
Truffle v4.0.5 (core: 4.0.5)
Solidity v0.4.18 (solc-js)
truffle(development)> web3.version
{ api: '0.20.3',
  node: [Getter],
  getNode: { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] },
  network: [Getter],
  getNetwork: { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] },
  ethereum: [Getter],
  getEthereum: { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] },
  whisper: [Getter],
  getWhisper: { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] } }
```

Apparently my truffle console is using v0.20.3 of web3.js. However, the [web3.js releases](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/releases) shows that it skips from 0.19 to 1.0-beta.

Comment: No, web3 v0.2.3 (from year 2015) is not the same as v0.20.3 (from 2017). New version are generated directly from master, and appear to not be tagged.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation can be found here: [Web3 JavaScript app API for 0.2x.x](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API)

Comment: So are 0.2.3 and 0.20.3 the same? Also, any idea how I can update my truffle web3 version?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38669/manually-set-web3-version-in-truffle

Answer (score 0):

The code for Web3 is in GitHub. Version 0.20.6 is tagged. You can go straight to the code for 0.20.6 at https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/v0.20.6.

0.20.3 doesn't seem to have been tagged, but I believe that https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/de3d64a4a9caa667642784f1aced78d5a89bb325 is the commit that was used.