# Manually set web3 version in truffle?

Tags: web3js, truffle

The version of web3 in Truffle v4.0.5 is v0.20.3. Is it possible to manually upgrade the web3 version?

---

Similar to [this question about web3 in geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/how-to-update-the-web3-api-version-in-geth). (It's hardcoded.)

Somewhat relevant to this [issue](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/166).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found this workaround. You can manually load a different version by loading it yourself:

First install some version:

```
npm install web3@1.0.0-beta.18
```

Then load it into the truffle console:

```
var Web3latest = require('web3');
var web3latest = new Web3latest();
```

Comment: I know this is old, but, for me (and others I've seen online), this results in an error that the provider is not set.